# Why more than one thread to get a wrong result

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to use multithreading to boost the speed of my code.It is a tool to help me calculate a specific seed of pvz.I just use one thread to run code(just like `int num = 1`)the program will get a right result,but **when I use more than one thread the program will get a random result or just no result**.

Because it's a cpu intensive processing and the problem can be split into subproblems easily, I have to use multithreading to let all cpu cores work.But the two versions has few differences, the multithread version has two features:

- enum seed two by two or more instead of one by one
- when one thread get result notice the others to stop

I achieved this through the code below(main thread):

```
int num = thread::hardware_concurrency();
vector<thread> threadList;
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    threadList.push_back(thread(&seedCalc::calcThread, this, num, i + offset));
}
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    threadList[i].join();
}
```

I use a global variable to swap data.For each thread, I use a while with condition `res == 0`(default) and when processing is done the res will be assigned.To prevent potentially confrontational problems I also use std::atomic as the result variable.

But errors occurred when I suppose everything has done.One thread is OK, but multithreading is wrong.I researched and logged out every step the value of `__seed`.There is something interesting using multi version.

- If I add some delay into the loop the multi version will be OK.
- I use debugger and found that each thread runs at a extremely low speed with high cpu usage.

I have no idea which part of the code has issues, is the logic has faults or the swaping process is wrong.

**The function `appear` doesn't affect the whole program it's just an internal function to return an arrry.I guess the issue possibly appears in function`seedCalc::calcThread`, especally**

```
......
if (fullFilled)break;
else seed += step;
}
if (!res)res = seed;
```

Here is the full code you can try it and give me some advice.There is an example in `main` function and its expected result should be `114452`.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

atomic_int res = 0;

inline bool* appear(int uid, int mode, const string& scene, int level, int seed)
{
    static bool havez[34];
    memset(havez, 0, sizeof(havez));
    havez[0] = true;
    if (level == 0)
    {
        havez[2] = true;
        havez[4] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        int rd = uid + mode + 0x65 * level + seed;
        if (rd == 0x0)rd = 0x1105;
        mt19937 rng(rd);
        int rd1 = (rng() & 0x7FFFFFFF) % 5;
        if (rd1 == 0x0)havez[5] = true;
        else havez[2] = true;
        int typeRem = 9;
        if (level < 9)typeRem = level + 1;
        int typeHave = 0;
        while (typeHave < typeRem)
        {
            int rd2 = (rng() & 0x7FFFFFFF) % 33;
            if (havez[rd2])continue;
            else if (rd2 == 9 || rd2 == 10 || rd2 == 13 || rd2 == 19 || rd2 == 24 || rd2 == 26 || rd2 == 27 || rd2 == 28 || rd2 == 29 || rd2 == 30 || rd2 == 31)continue;
            else if (scene == "NIGHT" && rd2 == 12)continue;
            else if ((scene != "POOL" && scene != "FOG") && (rd2 == 11 || rd2 == 14))continue;
            else if ((scene == "ROOF" || scene == "MOON") && (rd2 == 8 || rd2 == 17))continue;
            else if ((level < 2) && (rd2 == 12 || rd2 == 23))continue;
            else if ((level < 5) && (rd2 == 32))continue;
            else
            {
                havez[rd2] = true;
                typeHave++;
            }
        }
        havez[1] = false;
        havez[25] = false;
    }
    return havez;
}

class seedCalc
{
    public:
        void calc(const vector<int>& idNeeded, const vector<int>& idRefused);
        void calcThread(int __offset, int step);
        int uid, mod, level_ending, offset, level_beginning;
        string scene;
        vector<int> idNeeded;
        vector<int> idRefused;
        seedCalc(int uid, int mod, const string& scene, int level_beginning, int level_ending, int offset)
        {
            this->uid = uid;
            this->level_beginning = level_beginning;
            this->level_ending = level_ending;
            this->mod = mod;
            this->offset = offset;
            this->scene = scene;
        }
};

void seedCalc::calcThread(int step, int __offset)
{
    int seed = __offset;
    while (!res)
    {
        bool fullFilled = true;
        for (int lvl = level_beginning; lvl < level_ending; ++lvl)
        {
            bool* zombies = appear(uid, mod, scene, lvl, seed);
            for (int i = 0; i < idNeeded.size(); ++i)
            {
                int index = idNeeded[i];
                if (!zombies[index])
                {
                    fullFilled = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (!fullFilled)break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < idRefused.size(); ++i)
            {
                int index = idRefused[i];
                if (zombies[index])
                {
                    fullFilled = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (!fullFilled)break;
            }
        }
        if (fullFilled)break;
        else seed += step;
    }
    if (!res)res = seed;
}

void seedCalc::calc(const vector<int>& idNeeded, const vector<int>& idRefused)
{
    this->idNeeded = idNeeded;
    this->idRefused = idRefused;

    int num = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    vector<thread> threadList;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        threadList.push_back(thread(&seedCalc::calcThread, this, num, i + offset));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        threadList[i].join();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a({ 21 });
    vector<int> b({ 12, 15 });
    seedCalc s(1, 11, "DAY", 1, 7, 0);
    s.calc(a, b);
    cout << res << endl;
}
```

Comment: `__offset` is one of the reserved names, so remove that from your code first. Then, function-static variables are shared between threads, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of sychronization. Further, cramming multiple statements in one line, like condition and body in case of `if`, that is probably supposed to be a speed optimization, right? It just makes the code less readable. Magic numbers.

Comment: likely, the problem is in the `appear` funcition. there is a `static bool havez[34];` within the function, and being static  `havez` is not local to the function, it's the same `havez` for every call of the function. Now you are calling the function from multiple thread, each working on the same `havez`, reading and writing. what can go wrong? consider using a (not static) std:array<bool, 24> instead of a static variable. local static variable are not so different from global ones where you start dealing with multithreding: you need to handle concurrent access the same way more or less

Comment: Concerning `rd2 == 26 || rd2 == 27 || rd2 == 28 || rd2 == 29 || rd2 == 30 || rd2 == 31`: Why not `rd2 >= 26 && rd2 <= 31`?

Comment: `if (!res)res = seed;` is not atomic, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange `res.compare_exchange_strong(0, seed);